# Javascript type. Trying to understand how it works under the hood

Tags: javascript, typing

I found some weird things about Javascript. For instance when I run in a node Shell (by just typing node) there are some statements that I do not understand.

```
    > [] + []
    ''                           (because [] is converted to an empty string ?)
    > {} + []
    0                            (why 0 ?)
    > x = ['10', '10', '10']     (this is ok)
    ['10', '10', '10']
    > x.map(parseInt)
    [ 10, NaN, 2 ]               (really weird)
```

I would like to know how Javascript works under the hood to understand why I get those results (especially the last one)

Comment: The last example you have is mentioned in the mdn documentation for `map()` at the 'Tricky use Case' section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map . In summary, the problem comes from optional function parameters.

Comment: The ECMAScript spec is the place to look if you want to know how things are designed to work. Right now, this is an accumulation of commonly asked questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been already answered many times, here's a quick outline of what's going on:

```
> [] + []
    = String([]) + String([])
    = [].join() + [].join()
    = '' + ''

> {} + []
    = {/*empty block */}; +[]
    = Number([])
    = Number(String([]))
    = Number('')
    = 0

> x = ['30', '20', '10']
> x.map(parseInt)
    = [
        parseInt('30', 0),
        parseInt('20', 1),
        parseInt('10', 2)
    ]
    = [10, NaN, 2]
```